# Approximate a continuous function defined on a non-compact domain

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, approximation

Write $C[a,\infty)$ for the set of all real-valued continuous functions defined on $[a,\infty)$.
Let $\emptyset \neq K \subset C[a,\infty)$ which satisfies $\forall f, g \in K$, we have $h \in K$ where $h(x) = min\{f(x),g(x)\} \forall x \in [a,\infty)$.

Let $g \in C[a,\infty)$. Suppose that $g(x) =$ inf$\{f(x): f \in K; f \geq g\} \forall x ∈ [a,\infty)$.
Can we approximate such $g$ by functions in $C[a,\infty)$?
That is $\forall \epsilon > 0$, does there exists some $f \in K$ such that $|f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon \forall x \in [a,\infty)$?

My idea is no because the domain is non-compact.

Comment: As we already *have* $g\in C[A,\infty)$, what s the problem? Also note that $g(x)=\inf\{\ldots; f\ge g\,\}$ is tautological

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have edited the question.

Comment: You wanted to write "Can we approximate such $g$ (uniformly(?)) by functions in $K$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is unbounded, it looks false. Let for example $K$ be the set of piecewise linear continuous functions with a finite number of pieces and let $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Clearly $g$ cannot be approximated uniformly by elements of $K$.

In the bounded case, it looks false as well, take for $K$ the set of piecewise linear continuous bounded functions with a finite number of pieces and let $g(x)=\sin(x)$. The same problem occurs.

Comment: That looks like a very nice counter example.